# Sorting units Java Program

Tags: java

My approach:
First i am taking input as string later i am splitting with split method to get array of [day,hour,second, minute] 
For next input i'm splitting using split("=") but i'm not getting how make relation for other.

Write a program to sort a set of given units and output a single relationship equation among the units in descending order of size> The input given will be a series of comma separated units and a set of relationship equations between them. From these equations, you are expected to derive a single relationship equation in descending order of the units, with the largest unit on the left.
Further the following are given:
1. The number of equations given will be 1 less than the bumber of units given.
2. To keep t simple, only units that can be expressed as integer multiples of each other should be considered.

Sample Input
`day,hour,second,minute
day = 24 hour
hour = 60 minute
minute = 60 second`

Sample Output
`1day = 24hour = 1440minute = 86400second`

Comment: not to speak that the images are unreadable...

Answer (score 0):

> Just something off the top of my head.

You mentioned you could split the string and get array of the units. Let's call them 'unitsArr'

```
String unitsArr = [day, hour, second, minute]
```

Nice work. Now you are stuck on getting the relations right.

Split the string of inputs of these relations by whitespace

```
day = 24 hour
hour = 60 minute
minute = 60 second
```

with something like this :

```
str.split("\\s+");
```

And store them in a way where you are able to get these arrays of strings.

```
String biggerUnit = [day, hour, minute]
String relationUnit = [24, 60, 60]
String smallerUnit = [hour, minute, second]
```

You can see that the positions do matter here.

Now iterate through the 'unitsArr' and check them in 'biggerUnit' and then the relative 'smallerUnit' again in 'biggerUnit'. Keep a counter and increase it every time it goes through a successful check in 'biggerUnit'.

```
int counter = 0;
```

For example:

```
unitsArr[0] = "day"
```

If you find 'day' in 'biggerUnits', it goes through. The relative 'smallerUnit' is hour. Because

```
biggerUnit[0] = "day"
smallerUnit[0] = 'hour'
```

which is present in the array 'biggerUnit' as well. The following shows the flow:

> counter = 0
>
> day -> hour  -------> ++counter -> 1
>
> hour -> minute -----> ++counter -> 2
>
> minute -> second ---> ++counter -> 3
>
> The counter stops here as the unit 'second' is not present in 'biggerUnit' hence counter = 3.

Just like this, the counters for the different units will have different values.

```
days -----> counterDays = 3
hour -----> counterHour = 2
minute ---> counterMinute = 1
second ---> counterSecond = 0
```

And these counters represent the order or the ranks in the descending order. Making use of this order and the given array 'relationUnit' I think you can work your way to the solution.

Fellow users, do suggest better approaches as this one is highly unoptimized.

Note for the OP: At least, you could have tried out a solution and then added a question here. This is not somewhere you get your assignments done.